# Passing a variable as a parameter in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I need to pass a module attribute as a function parameter, however it doesn't work for me and it raises an error. Here is my code:

```
defmodule Waiter do
    @defaultInterval 1
    @defaultTimeout 10
    def wait(condition, timeout, interval) do
        IO.puts "condition #{condition} timeout #{timeout} interval #{interval}"
    end
    def wait(condition, timeout), do: wait(condition, timeout, Waiter.defaultInterval)
    def wait(condition), do: wait(condition, Waiter.defaultTimeout, Waiter.defaultInterval)
end

Waiter.wait("condition", 2, 20)
Waiter.wait("condition", 2)
Waiter.wait("condition")
```

I'm getting a warning about `@defaultInterval` and `@defaultTimeout` declared but not being used, and then an error:

```
iex(4)> Waiter.wait("condition", 2)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Waiter.defaultInterval/0 is undefined or private
    Waiter.defaultInterval()
    iex:7: Waiter.wait/2
```

If I will pass just a value (e.g. `Waiter.wait("condition", 1, 10)`), that will work.

How can I refactor my code so it would work properly?

Comment: For what it's worth, try not to think in terms of objects and properties.  `Waiter.defaultInterval` is the kind of syntax you'd see in OO languages.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci what do you suggest instead?

Comment: I mean it looks like you're thinking in terms of `defaultInterval` being a property of `Waiter`.  That's not the case. There's nothing that ties Waiter and defaultInterval together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Module attributes are accessed the same way they're declared: with the `@` before the name:

```
def wait(condition, timeout), do: wait(condition, timeout, Waiter.defaultInterval)
def wait(condition), do: wait(condition, Waiter.defaultTimeout, Waiter.defaultInterval)
```

should be

```
def wait(condition, timeout), do: wait(condition, timeout, @defaultInterval)
def wait(condition), do: wait(condition, @defaultTimeout, @defaultInterval)
```

---

Sidenote: In Elixir these names are conventionally written in `snake_case`, e.g. `@default_timeout`.